# go on the line where a variable define on any editor

Tags: programming, vim, text-editor, editor, geany

Is there any add-on or ability on geany or any known linux editor for this purpose : when you click on one variable . The mouse coursor goes to when it initialize. 
My code is c language. what I am looking for is some thing like this: highlight one variable and then press one key or any act and finally the editor put your mouse cursor on the line which for the first time this argument define or initialize.

Comment: You really need to tell us what programming language(s) you have on your mind.

Comment: @MadMike I code is written by C language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `geany`, there is already functionality to jump to the definition of the variable/function. With the right key via the context menu, or by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> (after selecting the item) you can jump to the definition.
**Note:** The only limitation is that the file that contains the definition must already be open in geany, otherwise it will not work.

Example:

Define variable:

[image: define variable]

Guake go to definition.

[image]

This work for type definition and functions; if you have to look for an instance of a variable within the document or project, you have to look for it as text.

Comment: whould please add an example. I define int abc=1; then some lines lower on that function I use abc , after that I select abc and press CRTL + T, but I it says: definition of "abc" is not found

Comment: @alex I've edited my answer with a little example.

Answer (score 1):

IDEs like Geany, Eclipse, etc. all usually have this feature. If you don't want to go for IDEs, you can try `ctags` and `vim` or `emacs`. I don't know how to use it in `emacs`, but for `vim`, you run `ctags` in the directory containing your source, then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to jump back and forth between a variable/function/class/... and its definition.

```
sudo apt-get install exuberant-ctags
# in source directory
ctags -R .
vim -t <tag>
# This does the same thing as Ctrl-] while the cursor is on <tag> within vim.
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563616/vim-and-ctags-tips-and-tricks for more information.
@lion suggests using TagList plugin for vim - http://amix.dk/blog/post/19329

PS: The program is named `ctags`, but it can be used for many programming languages other than C.

PPS: The keyboard shortcuts were wrong. I have use the correct defaults now.

Comment: thanks, how to install ctag on vim: http://amix.dk/blog/post/19329